# How to Track an event when a DIV gets visible with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, overlay, event-tracking, jwplayer6

So, I have a JWPlayer 6.11 to play a video, when the video is complete, the user gets an overlay DIV "window" with an offer.
The overlay DIV has display:none; CSS style when it is inactive.

How do I trigger an event with GA when the DIV becomes visible?

Here's the JavaScript code I'm using to embed a video and show the overlay DIV when video ends:

```
<script>
jwplayer("video").setup({
    width: "640",
    height: "480",
    image: "http://example.com/cdc9aZuj.jpg",
    file: "http://example.com/movies/movie.mp4",
    ga: {
        idstring: "file"
    },
    events: {
        onComplete: function() {
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The simple solution would be to add the event tracking code in the onComplete event - is there any reason why you do not want to do this ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I don't know how to do that :( Could you show me an example please?

Comment: Which google analytics tracking code are you implementing?universal or classic?

Comment: @carlodurso - Universal

Comment: That's all you need: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events